# Immediately trigger function if Global var becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have global variable e.g. `window.remote.storageData` that is filled on script running. However, in some cases it becomes undefined explicitly. In those cases I`d like to trigger function in order to reload it.
I used setInterval for this:

```
setInterval(function(){...},timer);
```

However, if the var becomes undefined in range of timer I got errors in my code.
Tiny timer gap is stuck my application, those the solution with timer less then 500 is not working well.

Is there are some ways to trigger function immediately when variable value is changed?

Comment: or setters/getters

Comment: Yes, it's called a setter: [MDN - Defining_getters_and_setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ES5 browsers and `remote` is not frozen you can define a property with custom get/set.

```
(function(remote) {
  var value = remote.storageData;

  try {
    Object.defineProperty(remote, 'storageData', {
       get: function() { return value;}

       set: function(newVal) {
         if(typeof newVal === 'undefined') {
            newVal = //some code to get value
         }

         value = newVal
       }
    })
  } catch(e) {
     console.log(e)
  }
}(window.remote))
```

But some code could still replace entire `window.remote` object. In this case you'll need to define `remote` property with custom get/set on `window` itself.

Comment: Thanks, that what I looking for